# AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator' when trying to import excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is my code.
I've just installed jupyterlab and i've added the excel file in there.
Same error if i change the path to where the file is on my system.
I can't seem to find anyone who had the same problem when simply importing an excel file as a dataframe.

The excel file is a 3x26 table with studentnr, course, result columns that have values like 101-105, A-D, 1.0-9.9 respectively. Maybe the problem lies with the excel file?

Either way i have no idea how to fix this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('student-results.xlsx')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9d38e4d56bbe> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 df = pd.read_excel('student-results.xlsx')

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols)
    302 
    303     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 304         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    305     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    306         raise ValueError(

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine)
    865         self._io = stringify_path(path_or_buffer)
    866 
--> 867         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    868 
    869     def __fspath__(self):

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     20         err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
     21         import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
---> 22         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
     23 
     24     @property

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    351             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    352         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str):
--> 353             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    354         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, bytes):
    355             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(filepath_or_buffer))

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     35             return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
     36         else:
---> 37             return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
     38 
     39     @property

c:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    128         if 'xl/workbook.xml' in component_names:
    129             from . import xlsx
--> 130             bk = xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml(
    131                 zf,
    132                 component_names,

c:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py in open_workbook_2007_xml(zf, component_names, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    810     del zflo
    811     zflo = zf.open(component_names['xl/workbook.xml'])
--> 812     x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
    813     del zflo
    814     props_name = 'docprops/core.xml'

c:\python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py in process_stream(self, stream, heading)
    264         self.tree = ET.parse(stream)
    265         getmethod = self.tag2meth.get
--> 266         for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():
    267             if self.verbosity >= 3:
    268                 self.dump_elem(elem)

AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Comment: Super annoying bug, I hope this gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 37):

You could try to use an argument `engine="openpyxl"`. It helped me to resolve the same problem.

Answer (score 34):

I got the same error with xlrd (1.2.0) or xlrd3 (1.0.0) without pandas, but with Python 3.9. The following may interest those looking for an explanation:

It only happened when defusedxml was available (in that case, xlrd will use it).
But it could be worked around, without changing any of the involved libraries:

```
import xlrd
xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True
```

The second line ensures that `Element_has_iter` will not be reset when opening a workbook, so that it remains to True - as set in the 3rd line. When this is done, xlrd uses `iter` instead of crashing on the missing `getiterator`.

That said, I agree that moving to openpyxl in place of xlrd is a cleaner solution, at least untill xlrd or xlrd3 possibly gets fixed. Openpyxl appears to be more actively developed. In my case, I have to adapt direct calls to those libraries, it is probably more work than just typing openpyxl instead of xlrd to tell pandas about what it should do, but I'll consider it.

So ok with @corridda, use openpyxl, and others are right about the cause, but maybe this explains a little more on the causes.

Comment: This is the true solution. I've just checked if there is an issue open for `xlrd` and I see they dropped support for xlsx files, so it won't be fixed.

Comment: the perfect solution. Thanx

Answer (score 20):

The error occurs when pandas is used in python3.9+ because the code `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getiterator()` which had been deprecated with a warning previously, has now been removed.

A workaround is to install another engine openpyxl to read the excel file, and replace your code which reads the excel file.

First,

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

Then, instead of `pd.read_excel('student-results.xlsx')`, write `pd.read_excel('student-results.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')`

Reference:
[Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue29209)

Comment: Here are some more details on what they're doing to pandas as a fix: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37795

Answer (score 15):

After reading the comments I can confirm that this one below worked perfectly.
Make sure you have XLRD version 1.2.0
New version of xlrd does not have the xlsx option.

```
pip install xrld==1.2.0 

import xlrd
xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True

pd.read_excel(path) #don't even need the engine=openpyxl
```

Worked in Python 3.9

Answer (score 11):

You can check issue description [here](https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/1640).
You run Python 3.9 and use **xlrd** library which call removed `getiterator` method. You should find part of code in the file from your *"Trace back"* and replace `getiterator` with `iter`.

It might require to run Python file and replace that calls couple times.

Comment: This should be the top answer. By far the simplest fix and it gets rid of the deprecated "getiterator".

Answer (score 4):

This showed up for me when I upgraded to Python 3.9. The difference seems to be related to a combination of the compression format of `xlsx` files and as the deprecation of an iterator function.

For `xlsx` documents I need to specify the `engine='openpyxl'` keyword argument when opening.

This is not the case for `csv` or `xls` documents.

**Install openpyxl**

```
$ pip3 install openpyxl
```

**Open `xlsx` and `xls` files with different engines.**

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = Path(file_name)

if file_path.suffix == '.xlsx':
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

elif file_path.suffix == '.xls':
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)

else:
    # handle other file types
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps:

1. Go to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlrd
2. open the xlsx.py in any text editor and replace the two getiterator() method  with iter().
3. Reload your Jupiter notebook. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while working on a course from stackskill. After looking around I found that the xlsx.py file itself has getiterator() and from what I had read it needs to be just iter().

There are only two sections in the xlsx.py file that require changing as far as I had noticed. It seemed to be an easy fix.

I will post the line of code that I have changed if you would like to modify them.

The first section of the code I came across is on line 266 and again on 312.

The original line for each should like this.

```
for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():
```

With the modification it should look like this.

```
for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.iter():
```

Make sure you make a copy of the file before modifying it but as of right now it seems to be working better then adding engine="openpyxl" as this seemed to only work partially with certain sections of code as opposed to others.

I hope this helps everyone out looking for a fix for this. I 've also included a link of where I found the fix.

https://www.programmersought.com/article/61207614127/

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

path = "C:\\Users\\user\\file\\pyfiles\\msbook1.xlsx" # your filepath and name and extension

xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True


book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)


print(1222222222222, sheet.cell_value(2,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these cmd and it work for my script:

```
import xlrd
xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this solution has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66766927/21144042), so maybe you should delete it.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid messing with `xlrd`, you can also save your Excel file with `.xls` extension instead of `.xlsx`.

Comment: AFAIK, that is wrong: one should use the more recent .xlsx, while the .xls files cannot be read by openpyxl. As I remember from a quick test, .xls file fail with xlrd too, anyway.