# Pandas pd.read_excel throwing error no matter the filename/path

Tags: python, pandas

when trying to run this line with every variation of file path name I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried all five of these filename paths and still the same error.

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Folder\\Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Folder\Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\Folder\Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Folder/Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

df = pd.read_excel('C://Users/Folder/Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Error:

```
for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Comment: Did you try solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264563/attributeerror-elementtree-object-has-no-attribute-getiterator-when-trying

Comment: try this ```df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Folder/Filename.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')``` if it doesn't solve your problem, add this ```from openpyxl import load_workbook``` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @student Thank you, that worked for me. Can you help me understand why that's important? I was convinced it had to do with the file string I was passing through.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I tried passing a raw string and I did not work. Student's solution works when I add the engine="openpyxl".

Comment: I am not exactly sure but looking into discussion in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21099, it could be something with excel file having pivot or images.

Comment: @student do you know if the '''df.to_excel(filepath,sheet_name=0,engine='openpyxl')''' will create a new tab for each sheet im importing?

Comment: sorry, I do not know. Probably others can answer about it.