# "'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getiterator'" when I try to make markdown filter for my blog

Tags: python, django, filter, markdown

Thanks for any of your answers!
My question is:

I learn Django with book "Django By Example". Now I'm learning "Custom template filters" chapter. And I do everything what author is telling to do. But there is a problem.

I get error, witch look like this:
"'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getiterator'"

I tried to write function in this way:

```
@register.filter(name='markdown')
def markdown_format(text):
    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(text))
```

and my list.html file looks like this:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load blog_tags %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>My Blog</h1>
  {% if tag %}
    <h2>Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="tags">
      Tags:
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
          {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|markdown|truncatewords_html:30 }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Full version of the previous code you can find here:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter03/mysite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator' when trying to import excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264563/attributeerror-elementtree-object-has-no-attribute-getiterator-when-trying)